# Is it possible to add scrolling news in tamil language using WordPress plugins on my WordPress site

Tags: fonts, scroll, wordpress, tamil

I want to show the latest events using tamil fonts on my wordpress site. Is it possible to add tamil fonts on any wordpress vertical news scroller.